# Static tableview cell stays highlighted when returning from different scene

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, interface-builder

I have a uiviewcontroller with a container on it, embedded inside of that is a uitableviewcontroller that has static cells and static content. When I tap the cell "Trip Info" it segues to the Trip Info View Controller. When coming back the static cell is highlighted.

I have seen many posts saying to add code to the didselectrow tableview method but I dont use one because my content is static. Any ideas?

Comment: you can also set the background colors of table view and its cell to be white, so the highlighted cell will be of same color as the rest of them.

Comment: I already have colors set and the highlight color doesn't match. That seems kind of hacky to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out on my own.

You need to make a swift file for that UITableViewController that is embedded into the UIViewController.

Then make sure your tableview is a delegate, and then call the

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

in that new file you created.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, just because you have static content doesn't mean you get to skip using the tableview delegate. It's not hard to set up.

```
 tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(index)
```

There's not another way.

Comment: So do I add a file for that uitableviewcontroller and put that code in the viewdidload? I am fairly new to iOS.

Comment: Also I dont see that option if I do that in the new file I created for the tableviewcontroller. All I see is, fuelTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndex, animated: true). I dont have an indexPath because Im not using tableview functions to dynamically add content.